# Emit data in loop via socket.io emit only once. How to send large data to client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, socket.io, large-data

i'm trying to code a web application with JS, Node.js and socket.io for plotting data, that inserting in sqlite base every second, in real-time. The thing is, that realtime fresh data emmiting via socketio.emit works correctly, but additionaly i need to send an existing data-set to client, that exist in databse on connection moment and then doing the real-time stuff. I figured out, that socketio.emit has limited size to emit and data in my DB might be about 8-9GB. I tried to emitting parts of this data via for..in loop, but client gets only the very first emit.

First, i used the "aa-sqlite" library as easiest way to get DB, but ended-up with this:

```
async function oldData(socket, f, m)
{ 
  var lastData = [];
  var i = 1;
  //var alldata = await aa_sqlite.all("SELECT * FROM liq");
  let db = new sql3.Database("D:\\sqlite\\book4.db")
  db.each("SELECT * FROM liq", async function (err, row) {
    lastData = data_done(row,f,m);
    socket.emit("FromAPIAll", lastData);
  });
  //
  console.log(lastData);
  
  console.log("Old Data Loaded");
}
```

Function for existing data set, using the "sqlite3" library, but it's also not emit in the "db.each" loop. And also i don't figure out how to save the data in the Object variable, after the db. function end, so the "console.log(lastData) shows nothing.

Also try set this in "setInterva", to emit bigger parts of data, but it didn't do a thing:

```
 await aa_sqlite.open("D:\\sqlite\\book4.db");
  var c = await aa_sqlite.all("SELECT * FROM liq")
  var db = prepareData(c, f, m);

  int = setInterval(() =>
  {
    if (db.length > 24999) {
      var cur = db.slice(0, 24999);
    }
    else {
      var cur = db.slice(0, db.length);
    }
    console.log(cur.length);
    socket.emit("FromAPIFull", cur);

        if (!db.length) {
      clearInterval(int);
    }
    if (db.length > 24999) {
      db = db.slice(25000)
    }
    else {
      db = db.slice(db.length)
    }
```

This code is under "io.on("connection", async (socket) => {..."

Do somebody have any suggestions to solve that situation?